# Rails - Role based Views using Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, view, partials, pundit

I am working on creating an app using Devise and Pundit to create users and assign them roles.

With that, I want to have role-based views in my app. I'm having a hard time thinking through how to make that possible.

When you login, if you're a `user` you should redirect to the `user` home view. If you're a `manager` you should redirect to a `manager` home view.

What's the best way, at a high level, to write that logic? Should it live in a controller, a view, perhaps utilize partials to keep things DRY....

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), each object should do the smallest possible useful thing. For Rails controllers, that thing is handling requests and rendering views with associated objects. So I would put that in a controller.

[Devise has a great wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out) on the subject of redirecting after a successful login.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the rolify gem for assigning and checking roles on users. In my limited experience it is pretty obvious where that logic goes, usually in the controller if you are going to redirect or render different views. Occasionally it's not unreasonable to put it in a view - for example, if you have a page listing a bunch of items that is the same for everyone, except that you want to show "delete" link next to each item only if the current user is an admin.

rolify - https://github.com/EppO/rolify

Answer (score 0):

i met the same problem, what i did was

1- create role column in user table

2- create enum in user model as

```
enum role: [:Manager, :Developer, :Quality]
```

3- create three partials

1. _manager.html.erb
2. _developer.html.erb
3. _quality.html.erb

4- create index.html.erb and put the following

```
<% if current_user.Manager? %>
<%= render "dashboard/manager" %>
<% elsif current_user.Developer?%>
<%= render  "dashboard/developer" %>
<% else %>
<%= render  "dashboard/quality" %>
<% end %>
```

thanks to: [Multiple Devise Users with different dashboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562621/multiple-devise-users-with-different-dashboards)